# Swift Color picker for user

Tags: swift, uicolor

I need some help on best direction for creating the following:

- An Colours picker that shows a number of colours as small circles
- Selected colour is a bigger circle
- Allow user to click to select their colour

See image for example of what I mean

[image]

I am a bit lost in the best way to create this, I am not looking for the code it self just a direction to go by to create this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using UICollectionView is the easiest available option.

1) Option 1

1. Use a custom UICollectionViewCell.
2. Add a view in it with constraints with respect to the superview i.e CollectionViewCell.
3. Give corner radius to the view to make it a circle.
4. On selection of the particular collectionViewCell, Update the size of the view and the corner radius to make the circle bigger.

Note : Save the indexPath of the previously selected cell if you want to decrease the size of the previously selected colour option.

2) Option2(Not suggested):

1. If the numbers of colours are limited. Use a stackView with buttons.
2. Customise the buttons to the required shape.
3. Updated the size of the button with respect to the superview i.e Stack.
4. You can have a single outlet for all the buttons. But you will have to save the instance of the selected button so as to update the previously selected button.